# How to search for a word that contains uppercase and lowercase letters in a TextBox and then replace it with another word

Tags: vb.net

I have a `TextBox` that includes more words

Example:

> I'm **pRoFeSSoinaL** coder

I want to search for the word **pRoFeSSoinaL** (that contains uppercase and lowercase letters) and then replace it.

Comment: why you cant just pur both string to upper check if match then do something if its match?

Comment: Are you wanting to search for any word in mixed case, or specific words in any case?

Answer (score 1):

OK let me try and address your problem again based on your image:

[image]

And on your comment:

> ...but i need search about word have More than a change of letters example (execute, ExEcute, eXecute, execUtE........ETC) i need find word No matter how large and small the letters are see this proof

Again, *if* I have this right, you would like to find all occurrences of a word regardless of it's case. In effect you would like for your application to work a bit like Notepad.

I've put together some code that will use the following methods:

- [String.ToLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Returns a copy of this string converted to lowercase.
- [TextBox.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Selects a range of text in the text box.
- [String.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in the current instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted.
- [String.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance.
- [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

I have three `Button` controls that I've put a bit a code behind. One will find the next occurrence of a word, another will replace the next occurrence of a word and the last one will replace all occurrences of a word.

Now it's not my job to design your application but for ease I have also popped on three `TextBox` controls. This is how my form looks:

[image]

To find the next occurrence of `professional` this is the code I used:

```
Private Sub btnFindNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindNext.Click

    'check word exists
    If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().Contains(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower()) Then
        'reset position if at end of text
        If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1) < 0 Then
            position = 0
        End If

        'set position of next occurrence
        position = txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1)

        'select next occurrence
        txtTextToSearch.Select(position, txtWordToFind.Text.Length)
    End If

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of how it would look when you click the button:

[image]

Clicking the button again will select the next occurrence of the word. It will keep toggling between the two in my example.

To replace the next occurrence of `professional` this is the code I used:

```
Private Sub btnReplaceNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReplaceNext.Click

    'check word exists
    If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().Contains(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower()) Then
        'reset position if at end of text
        If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1) < 0 Then
            position = 0
        End If

        'set position of next occurrence
        position = txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1)

        'remove old word
        txtTextToSearch.Text = txtTextToSearch.Text.Remove(position, txtWordToFind.Text.Length())
        'insert new word
        txtTextToSearch.Text = txtTextToSearch.Text.Insert(position, txtReplaceWith.Text)
    End If

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of how it would look when you click the button:

[image]

Clicking the button again will replace the next occurrence of the word.

To replace all occurrences of the word `professional` this is the code I used:

```
Private Sub btnReplaceAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReplaceAll.Click

    'check word exists
    If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().Contains(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower()) Then
        'reset position if at end of text
        If txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1) < 0 Then
            position = 0
        End If

        'set position of next occurrence
        position = txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1)

        While position > 0 AndAlso position < txtTextToSearch.Text.Length

            'remove old word
            txtTextToSearch.Text = txtTextToSearch.Text.Remove(position, txtWordToFind.Text.Length())
            'insert new word
            txtTextToSearch.Text = txtTextToSearch.Text.Insert(position, txtReplaceWith.Text)

            'set position of next occurrence
            position = txtTextToSearch.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(txtWordToFind.Text.ToLower(), position + 1)
        End While
    End If

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of how it would look when you click the button:

[image]

My code will need adapting I'm sure but it should give you something to go on. As for the level of detail I have gone to, may not benefit you but may benefit others that visit this question. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Black.JAC : Take it easy. We don't know what you know or don't know, there are lots of newcomers here who don't know how to use `String.Replace()`. I agree with Bugs that your question is very unclear, so please edit it and elaborate what it is you want to do. Giving examples of different situations is good (for instance when/what to match/don't match).

Comment: @Black.JAC I've updated answer. Please have a look, test it and let me know you think. It should give you what you are.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XolD2.png) you appear to be after *case-insensitive* string matching.

The simplest way is to use the [**`String.IndexOf(String, StringComparison)` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform case-insensitive comparison:

```
Private Function FindText(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Text As String) As Integer
    Return Source.IndexOf(Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
End Function
```

**Usage example:**

```
Dim TextToFind As String = "professional"
Dim TextPos As Integer = FindText(TextBox1.Text, TextToFind)

If TextPos > -1 Then 'Match found.
    TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextPos
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length
End If
```